# Manipulate color of QImage - QT

Tags: python, c++, image, qt, colors

I have one generic icon image, which has an alpha. Lets say a black sphere placed on an square button, with transparancy. 
Now I would like to change the color of the icon on the fly, without having several image of sphere_black.png, sphere_red.png etc etc. 
Is there a way to colorize the pixmap, respecting the alpha and change HSV on that pixel, for all in the map?

I have something like this, but stuck:

```
img = QtGui.QImage(kwargs['icon_path']
pxmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img)
for x in range(img.width()):
    for y in range(img.height()):
         print img.pixel(1, 1), '###'
         # ???? #
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[QGraphicsColorizeEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicscolorizeeffect.html) might be what you are looking for. Sadly the `QGraphicsEffect` class is made to be used with the graphics view framework, it can't easily be applied to a `QImage`. However there are workarounds for that, as [this discussion](https://forum.qt.io/topic/3477/render-qgraphicseffect-into-pixmap/7) shows.

The implementation of the effect in [QPixmapColorizeFilter::draw()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/effects/qpixmapfilter.cpp.html#1086) shows how the colourization is done: A coloured rect (with the color having the alpha set to something else than fully opaque) is drawn over the image with `QPainter::fillRect()`, with an appropriate composition mode set.